# Condition on selected option doesn't work

Tags: vue.js, selected, primevue

I'm using `PrimeVue` Datatable to show my products, in case of updating a product, i want to show the values of the product to update in the modal inputs, including `size` and whether the product is included in the best selling list or no, the condition for selected `size` works fine, but it doesn't work for `bestSelling`, i made sure that `form.bestSelling` is either 1 or 0, but the `:selected` binding condition doesn't work:

`Index.vue`

```
<Column field="size" header="Size"></Column>

<Column header="Best Selling">
   <template #body="slotProps">
       <p>
         {{ slotProps.data.bestSelling == 1 ? "Yes": "No" }}
       </p>
   </template>
</Column>
```

`UpdateProduct.vue`

```
import { useForm } from "@inertiajs/vue3";
const props = defineProps(["product"]);

const form = useForm("UpdateProduct", {
    name: props.product.name,
    nameAr: props.product.nameAr,
    description: props.product.description,
    descriptionAr: props.product.descriptionAr,
    size: props.product.size,
    quantityPerPacket: props.product.quantityPerPacket,
    bestSelling: props.product.bestSelling,
});

onMounted(() => {
    form.reset();
});

<div class="field">
   <select v-model="form.size">
      <option :selected="form.size == 'Large'">Large</option> // works
      <option :selected="form.size == 'Medium'">Medium</option> // works
      <option :selected="form.size == 'Small'">Small</option> // works
   </select>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <select v-model="form.bestSelling">
    <option :selected="form.bestSelling == 1">Yes</option> // doesn't work
    <option :selected="form.bestSelling == 0">No</option> // doesn't work
  </select>
</div>
```

I even did this and the option says `true` if its yes:

```
<option>{{ form.bestSelling == 1 }}</option> // returns true
```

even if i do this, still will not be selected:

```
<option :selected="form.bestSelling == 1"> // won't be selected even if the condition is definitely true
 {{ form.bestSelling == 1 }} 
</option>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting the `selected` attribute of `<option>`, set its `value` attribute and let Vue figure it out through the `v-model` on the `<select>`:

```html
<div class="field">
  <select v-model="form.bestSelling">
    <option :value="1">Yes</option>
    <option :value="0">No</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Here it is in a snippet:

```js
const { createApp, ref } = Vue;

const App = { 
  template: `  <div class="field">
    <select v-model="form.bestSelling">
      <option :value="1">Yes</option>
      <option :value="0">No</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  form.value is {{form.bestSelling}}
  `,
  data() {
    return {
      form: {bestSelling: 1}
    };
  }
}
const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
```

Though for a binary value, you might be better off with a [switch](https://primevue.org/inputswitch/), a checkbox or radio buttons.

Comment: this also doesn't work

Comment: I have added a snippet where you can see it working. If you use numbers as value, make sure to use `:value` or `v-bind:value`, not `value`, or you'll end up with strings. Does that help?

Comment: yeah it works, it didn't work at the beginning because i was saving ```bestSelling``` field as string in the database, it worked when i changed the type to boolean